# Postgresql json query

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have one table with one column jsonb with the text:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "AUTOMÓVEL",
    "partes": [
      {
        "fracao": 100,
        "documento": "111.111.111-11"
      }
    ],
    "atributos": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "MARCA",
        "valor": "FORD"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "MODELO",
        "valor": "FIESTA"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "RENAVAM",
        "valor": "RENAVAM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "AUTOMÓVEL",
    "partes": [
      {
        "fracao": 100,
        "documento": "111.111.111-11"
      }
    ],
    "atributos": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "MARCA",
        "valor": "FIAT"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "MODELO",
        "valor": "PALIO"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "RENAVAM",
        "valor": "RENAVAM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "AUTOMÓVEL",
    "partes": [
      {
        "fracao": 100,
        "documento": "111.111.111-11"
      }
    ],
    "atributos": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "MARCA",
        "valor": "HONDA"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "MODELO",
        "valor": "FIT"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "RENAVAM",
        "valor": "RENAVAM"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so i create a select:

```
select objetos
from protocolo 
where objetos @> '[{"id": 1 , "atributos": [{"nome": "MARCA", "valor" : "FIAT"}]}]'
```

but this select will return the column with all text, but I need to return only the element that match in my where clause

so I need to return only this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "AUTOMÓVEL",
    "partes": [
      {
        "fracao": 100,
        "documento": "111.111.111-11"
      }
    ],
    "atributos": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "MARCA",
        "valor": "FIAT"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "MODELO",
        "valor": "PALIO"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "RENAVAM",
        "valor": "RENAVAM"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select value
from protocolo
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(objetos)
where value @> '{"id": 1 , "atributos": [{"nome": "MARCA", "valor" : "FIAT"}]}';
```

Note that the json expression in the where clause has changed.

Comment: don`t works return the field objetos with all json inside(the role array)

Comment: "{"id": 1, "nome": "AUTOMÓVEL", "partes": [{"fracao": 100, "documento": "111.111.111-11"}], "atributos": [{"id": 3, "nome": "MARCA", "valor": "FIAT"}, {"id": 2, "nome": "MODELO", "valor": "PALIO"}, {"id": 1, "nome": "RENAVAM", "valor": "RENAVAM"}]}"

Comment: This is exactly what you wrote as an expected result in the question.